# Equating coefficients requires rearrangement of infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider a complete orthonormal set of basis functions $\mathbf{\Psi}_n$ in a region of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a function that fulfills the following two expansions:

$$E(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_n^\infty a_n \mathbf{\Psi}_n(\mathbf{r})$$

and

$$E(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{n'}^\infty b_{n'} \sum_n^\infty W_{n'n} \mathbf{\Psi}_n(\mathbf{r})$$

Both expansions converge uniformly.

My question is this: Can we deduce from the above information the following equation?

$$\sum_{n'}^\infty b_{n'} W_{n'n}  = a_n $$

The background of my question is this: In engineering literature, people often assume the above equation and justify that by writing something like "by comparing the coefficients of the two equations and using the orthogonality of $\mathbf{\Psi}_n$ ..."

However, in order to actually equate the coefficients, we would need that the second expansion reads

$$E(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_n^\infty \mathbf{\Psi}_n(\mathbf{r}) \sum_{n'}^\infty b_{n'}  W_{n'n} $$

which is a rearrangement of the actual expansion. In general, infinite sums may not be rearranged, so I ask myself if the fact that both expansions converge uniformly over a region in space is enough to justify the given statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I think that yes, the process of equating coefficients is justified in the given context.

Reason: In uniformly convergent series, we can interchange the order of summation and integration. We can thus use orthogonality to project out single summands of the inner series.

We start from
$$\sum_n^\infty a_n \mathbf{\Psi}_n(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{n'}^\infty b_{n'} \sum_n^\infty W_{n'n} \mathbf{\Psi}_n(\mathbf{r})$$

Let's assume the orthogonality relation of the $\mathbf{\Psi}_n$ is

$$ \int_S \mathbf{\Psi}_n(\mathbf{r}) \cdot \mathbf{\Psi}_{n'} (\mathbf{r}) d\mathbf{r} = \delta_{nn'}.$$

-> multiply both sides with $\mathbf{\Psi}_{n'}(\mathbf{r})$ and integrate over $S$ to obtain

$$\int_S \left(\sum_n^\infty a_n \mathbf{\Psi}_n(\mathbf{r}) \cdot \mathbf{\Psi}_{n'}(\mathbf{r})
\right) d\mathbf{r}
= 
\int_S \left( \sum_{n'}^\infty b_{n'} \sum_n^\infty W_{n'n} \mathbf{\Psi}_n(\mathbf{r})
\cdot \mathbf{\Psi}_{n'}(\mathbf{r})
\right) d\mathbf{r}$$

Now, interchange order of summation and integration to obtain the desired result.